# How do I change the kernel config for a specific machine in Yocto?

Tags: beagleboneblack, yocto, bitbake

I am building core-image-minimal with "beaglebone" as the target machine.

I'd like to edit the kernel config to remove some features to improve boot time.  I've learned I can do a bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel to launch the ncurses editor, but I don't really understand what configuration I'm editing.  Is it the one for beablebone, or just a generic kernel?

How do I take the base beablebone kernel config, edit it, and then have bitbake use it when I build core-image-minimal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the beaglebone is using which kernel.  You have to find its machine Configuration.  For example, [beaglebone.conf](https://github.com/beagleboard/meta-beagleboard/blob/master/common-bsp/conf/machine/beaglebone.conf)

In there, you will see `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-mainline"`

To determine which kernel for beaglebone, you need to find it within `recipes-kernel`.  For example, [linux-mainline](https://github.com/beagleboard/meta-beagleboard/blob/master/common-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-mainline_3.8.bb)

after that, to do configuration, we have 2 ways to get to the Kernel's graphical configuration utility.

1. `bitbake -c menuconfig linux-mainline`
2. `bitbake -c devshell linux-mainline`

   `make nconfig`

There is a tutorial on installing drivers [HERE](http://alextgalileo.altervista.org/blog/reconfiguring-linux-kernel-adding-drivers-galileos-linux-image/)

Comment: It has to be mentioned that this is a "one time configuration" - it will not be applied at your buddy's house when he tries to use your layer! Therefore we need to know how to modify the Beaglebone's Linux configuration permanently!